# sample from more than one column

Tags: r, random

I have a df of numeric character values which looks like this -

```
set.seed(89)
a <- sample(1:30, 25, replace = T) 
b <- sample(1:30, 25, replace = T) 
d <- cbind(a,b)
```

I now want to sample into two new columns V1 and V2 for the length as d, from those distinct character values, with replacement, but I keep getting replicated columns (V1 = V2).

```
v1 <- d %>%
  select(a)
v2 <- d %>%
  select(b) 

n <- nrow(r)

 r <- rbind(v1, v2) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  rename(ID = V1) %>%
  mutate(ID = as.character(ID), 
         r_ID1 = sample(c(ID), n, replace = T), 
         r_ID2 = sample(c(ID), n, replace = T))
```

This feels like I am missing something obvious ?

Comment: Could you please provide your code for what you are trying to do, when you describe that you "sample into two new columns V1 and V2 for the length as d, from those distinct character values"? For all we can see is `d`, whose two columns are not identical.

Comment: sorry I am not very good at conveying what I am trying to do here. I've made some quick edits.

Comment: Do yo want something like `matrix(sample(unique(d), length(d), TRUE), ncol=2)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
> matrix(sample(unique(c(d)), prod(dim(d)), replace = TRUE), nrow(d))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   24    5
 [2,]    8    6
 [3,]   15   23
 [4,]   11    6
 [5,]   17   16
 [6,]   26   12
 [7,]   15   29
 [8,]   15   15
 [9,]   14    2
[10,]   22   17
[11,]   30    9
[12,]   23   24
[13,]    2   21
[14,]   16   24
[15,]   27   18
[16,]   30   29
[17,]    4    8
[18,]   11    5
[19,]   30   23
[20,]    5    6
[21,]    7    5
[22,]   20   17
[23,]    5   12
[24,]   13   15
[25,]    4   30
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me for some reason. I've amended my question.